# dropdown with selected item, how to get its name/ label using capybara

Tags: label, drop-down-menu, capybara

Given the following dropdown:

```
<select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
  <option value="1">Peter</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Pan</option>
</select>
```

I know I can get the value (2 here) of the current selection using this code:

```
find_field("#my-dropdown").value
```

But how can I get the name/ label (Pan here) of the current selection? The following code does **not** work:

```
find_field("#my-dropdown").label
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use css3 selectors to find the selected item,

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

and call the 'text' method on the element to get the text.

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element:text

Try:

```
find_field('#my-dropdown option[selected]').text
```

Comment: This will only work if the "selected" attribute is explicitly set on one of the option elements. A foolproof way to do it would be to find the `selectedIndex` of the dropdown and then use the `:nth-child` pseudo-selector to grab the currently selected option (which would be `selectedIndex + 1`)

Comment: I did not debug it but `find_field` did not work with capybara 2.3.0. `find('#my-dropdown option[selected]').text` worked fine

Answer (score 4):

While other answers came close, they did not seem to work with Capybara 1.1.2 (the version that I'm using). With that version I found that the following approach worked, but only because I knew what the value "should" be.

```
#based on Capybara::Node::Actions#select
def find_select_option(select_finder, option_finder)
  no_select_msg = "cannot select option, no select box with id, name, or label '#{select_finder}' found"
  no_option_msg = "cannot select option, no option with text '#{option_finder}' in select box '#{select_finder}'"
  select = find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.select(select_finder), :message => no_select_msg)
  select.find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.option(option_finder), :message => no_option_msg)
end

find_select_option('Countries', 'United States').should be_selected
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer using labels you can chain a find:

```
find_field('My Dropdown').find('option[selected]').text
```

The find searches within the context of the find_field.

Comment: This only works for default options, not when the input changes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by M. Scott Ford I was able to come up with the following function (where field is a id)

```
  def field_should_have_value(field, value)
    element = @session.find_field(field)
    if !element
      throw "field_should_have_value(#{field}, #{value}) - unable to fine field: #{field}"
    end

    # Question: is there any other way of doing: if element[:nodeName] == "select"
    option = element.has_selector?("option") && element.find(:xpath, XPath::HTML.option(value))
    if option
      if element.value != value && option.text != value
        throw "field_should_have_value(#{field}, #{value}) - value does not match. Expected: #{value}. Got element.value: #{element.value} || option.text: #{option.text}"
      end
    elsif element.value != value
      throw "field_should_have_value(#{field}, #{value}) - value does not match. Expected: #{value}. Got element.option.text: #{option.text}"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!
`find('#MyFieldId option[selected]').text`